# Javascript get content of URL

Tags: javascript

If I enter this link, I get an array of search suggestions for the word 'sun' in a textfile 'f.txt'

```
http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q=sun
```

How can I get this into an array in Javascript using only this URL?

Answer (score 3):

You can make a request using [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) and then parse the result into a JavaScript object using `JSON.parse`:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState === 4) {
        var response = req.responseText;
        var json = JSON.parse(response);

        console.log(json)
    }
};

req.open('GET', 'http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q=sun');
req.send(null);
```

Comment: @Kaiido Cross-origin error is definitely a problem, but parsing the response works fine.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this? It doesn't work this way.

Comment: @user3744885 The only way I can think of is to set up a reverse proxy for this request with cross-origin properly set up. For example a page on your site written in PHP that loads the content for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            return xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, false );
    xmlhttp.send();    
}
```

Comment: Please add a description to your code and explain what it does.